# iOS location regions firing events incorrectly since app has been built with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

So I have an iOS application that was built with Xcode 7 up until recently.  It uses iOS location regions for determining if users enter/exit regions.  I simply have code in the DidDetermineState method of the CLLocationManagerDelegate that sends API calls to my backend based on the state (entered/left).  It was working very well with very minimal issues up until I upgraded my build machine to Xcode 8 and made a new build.  Suddenly, some users are reporting "flip flopping" where they'll be sleeping and their phone will "enter home" then "left home" all while the phone is sitting on their night stand.  This never happened before upgrading to Xcode 8.  Were there some location changes in Xcode 8 that I missed that I'm not accounting for?

What's strange is I cannot reproduce it.  And they claim that it's working normally, but misfiring a lot.  I'm looking at their logs and seeing exactly what they're describing.  It'll be 3am and DidDetermineState will fire with "left home" only to "enter home" seconds or minutes later.  This seems to be ~10+% of users (total rough estimation).

```
public override void DidDetermineState(CLLocationManager manager, CLRegionState state, CLRegion region)
    {
        this.HandleRegionEnterExitDebugStuff("Did Determine State = " + state, manager, region);

        //Console.WriteLine("region.id = " + region.Identifier);

        // This is all code that hasn't changed in a long time and worked fine when built with Xcode 7.  But this event is misfiring (false positives) with Xcode 8....

        string message = null;

        switch (state)
        {
            case CLRegionState.Inside:
                RegionLogic (region, manager, "Region Entered", LocationManager.Location_WebHook_Enter);
                break;

            case CLRegionState.Outside:
                RegionLogic (region, manager, "Region Exit", LocationManager.Location_WebHook_Exit);
                break;

            case CLRegionState.Unknown:
                message = String.Format("DidDetermineState state = CLRegionState.Unknown for region.Identifier = " + region.Identifier);
                LogManager.LogMessage(
                    LogManager.LogType.Location,
                    message
                );
                LogManager.LogMessage(
                    LogManager.LogType.CriticalInfo,
                    message
                );
                break;

            default:
                message = String.Format("DidDetermineState state = invalid for region.Identifier = " + region.Identifier);
                LogManager.LogMessage(
                    LogManager.LogType.Location,
                    message
                );
                LogManager.LogMessage(
                    LogManager.LogType.CriticalInfo,
                    message
                );
                break;                  
        }
    }
```

Additional information:
So far i've dug into 3 users and confirmed they're seeing "false positives" via their logs and they have the following information:

- User 1: iOS 10.3.1 iPhone 6s. Location USA. Language English.
- User 2: iOS 10.3.1 iPhone 6s. Location USA. Language English.
- User 3: iOS 10.3.2 (beta version) iPhone 7. Location USA. Language English.
- Me (cannot reproduce issue): iOS 10.3.1 iPhone 6.  Location USA.  Language English.

Application is built with Xamarin.iOS
Target Deployment is 9.0

Comment: Did you change the SDK you built against? Are the false positives all caused by one version of iOS? Is there a common denominator in hardware/software between the users experiencing issues? What ideas have you tried so far to solve the problem (help us to help you)?

Comment: @RoboticCat so i've added some more info above from the 3 cases i've dug deep into.  The target deployment has not changed for this build, it's been at 9.0 for a while.

Comment: What is the radius of the region you are defining?

Comment: @Paulw11 It varies per user.  The smallest region I allow them is 100 meters.  Most users use 100m, sometimes they'll use larger.